# Is there a way to use sortProperties inline, in a template?

Tags: ember.js

I created several controllers and templates like the following for the sole purpose of sorting a property.

For example:

```
App.ExamplesController = Ember.ArrayController({
  sortProperties: ['index']
});
```

Template ('examples'):

```
{{#each}}
  {{foo}}
{{/each}}
```

Template ('app'):

```
<h1>MyApp</h1>
{{render 'examples' offers}}
```

Is there a less verbose way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add this as a new answer because it's so different. This is pretty tricky, and you'll need to modify it for your exact needs, but here's the basics. You're going to create a `sorted-each` component. First, the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/sorted-each">
    {{#each sortedContent}}
        {{yield}}
    {{/each}}
<script>
```

Now we're going to declare the component class. We declare 3 properties that you will pass into the component. Then we created a computed property to sort the content. Then, we override the `_yield` method because by default, it gives us the wrong context.

```
App.SortedEachComponent = Em.Component.extend({
    content: null,
    key: null,
    reverse: false,

    sortedContent: function() {
        return Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.SortableMixin, {
            content: this.get('content'),
            sortProperties: [this.get('key')],
            sortAscending: !this.get('reverse')
        });
    }.property('content', 'key', 'reverse'),

    _yield: function(context, options) {
        var get = Ember.get,
            view = options.data.view,
            parentView = this._parentView,
            template = get(this, 'template');

        if (template) {
            Ember.assert("A Component must have a parent view in order to yield.", parentView);
            view.appendChild(Ember.View, {
                isVirtual: true,
                tagName: '',
                _contextView: parentView,
                template: template,
                context: get(view, 'context'), // the default is get(parentView, 'context'),
                controller: get(view, 'controller'), // the default is get(parentView, 'context'),
                templateData: { keywords: parentView.cloneKeywords() }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, let's use it!

```
{{#sorted-each content=items sortKey=itemKey1 reverse=true}}
    Property1: {{itemKey1}}
    Property2: {{itemKey2}}
{{/sorted-each}}
```

You'll probably want to modify the component a bit to your liking, but as you can see, it does work. (At least it should. Let me know if there's any typos.)

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! I edited your response for typos in the usage of the component. But it seems that you must accept the edition for it to be displayed.

Comment: Warning: it seems that actions in components inside {{#sorted-each}} no longer works. As a result, don't nest components inside this one.

Answer (score 2):

I was literally just looking for this 20 minutes ago. I don't know about in the template, but you can do it in your `model` hook, which eliminates the need for declaring a controller:

```
model: function() {
    return Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.SortableMixin, {
        sortProperties: ['index'],
        content: this.get('store').find('widget', [1,2,3,4])
    });
}
```

EDIT: Of course this is kind of mixing in some domain logic into your route, so it might not be the preferred way to do things, but it's what I ended up using.

Comment: This is very useful, but unfortunately not applicable in my application. I got a lot of nested stuff, so I can't use the router and have a route for each collection I need to sort.
So I would really something either inline, or maybe at the ember data level but I kind of doubt it's possible. For now I have 10 added controllers just to sort stuff !

Comment: I posted another answer with something you might like a little more. :)